# Git Filter-Branch All command

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

At the moment, I'm currently using the command, "git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter MY_DIRECTORY -- --all" to grab a certain directory from all the 30 branches in this git repo. Before I do this filter branch command I make sure to checkout every branch to make sure the --all commands works properly.

My question is, do I have to checkout every branch before I do a git-filter all or will git-filter all still work without having to checkout all the 30 branches I'm looking at? Right now each branch is almost 3GB so this entire checkout process is taking a very long time. Any clarification would be great!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Before we start

Before I dive into the answer itself, note that if you want to have a local branch name for each of your remote-tracking names, you can simply create that local branch name without using `git checkout`:

```
git branch -t develop origin/develop
git branch -t feature/X origin/feature/X
git branch -t foo origin/foo
```

and so on.  This is a subset of what `git checkout` does, and is very fast since creating new branch names just means writing one file.

(If you like, you can use this technique and stop here, but the rest of this answer should be quite useful.)

#### The short and long answer

The short answer is that you do not have to check out (or create new) branch names.  But you will need to understand more than that to use Git (including this particular `git filter-branch` operation) well.

Let's start with this: `--all` here means *all references*.  But what's a "reference" then?

Well, any *branch name* is a reference.  But so is any *tag name*.  The special name `refs/stash`, used by `git stash`, is a reference.  Remote-tracking names are references.  Notes refs (from `git notes`) are references.  For more about this and other Git terms, see [the gitglossary](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitglossary.html) (note that this particular entry is under `ref` rather than `reference`).

When you first use `git clone` to clone a repository, you are telling your own Git: *make a new, independent copy of some existing repository, at the URL I give you, so that I can do my own work and then share it or not as I please.*  But *their* repository—whoever "they" are at the URL—has *its own* branch names.  They have *their* `master`, which is not always going to be the same as your `master`.  So your Git *renames* their names: their `master` becomes your `origin/master`, and so on.  These *remote-tracking names* are references.

After `git clone` finishes copying over to your repository all of their commits, and renaming all of their names to your remote-tracking names, the last step of `git clone` is to check out a branch.  But you don't *have* any branches yet.  This is where a special trick that `git checkout` does comes in: if you ask Git to checkout, by name, a branch that *doesn't exist*, Git looks through all of your remote-tracking names.  If one of those matches up, Git will *create* a local branch name—a new reference—that points to the *same* commit as this remote-tracking name.

Hence, your repository has some series of commits, all of which link to each other in a backwards fashion:

```
first  <--next ... <--almost-last  <--last
```

(if they're all linear, which they almost never are) which we can draw as:

```
A--B--...--H--I
```

where each uppercase letter represents a commit.  A set of commits with some "branchy-ness" (branchiness?) might look like:

```
     C--D
    /
A--B
    \
     E--F--G
```

and if there are merge commits, which point backwards to *two* previous commits instead of just one, it will be even more complicated.

The *names* we care most about here—branch names and remote-tracking names in particular—serve as a way for Git to *find* the last commit:

```
...--H--I   <-- origin/master
```

The name `origin/master` is said to *point to* commit `I`.  When your Git creates your own `master`, your `master` now *also* points to `I`:

```
...--H--I   <-- master, origin/master
```

If you create your own new commit on `master`, this is what happens:

```
...--H--I   <-- origin/master
         \
          J   <-- master
```

Git makes up a new ID for the new commit—it's some apparently-random big ugly hash ID, but here we just call it `J`—and then *changes* your name `master` to point to this new commit.

If you run `git fetch` and bring in new commits from `origin` and they have updated *their* master, you now get:

```
...--H--I--K   <-- origin/master
         \
          J   <-- master
```

and now your `master` and their `origin/master` have diverged.

These names, `master` and `origin/master`, have the important effect of making their commits *reachable*.  That is, by following the arrow from each name, Git can find commits `J` and `K`.  Then, using the backwards arrow—really the commit's *parent* commit hash ID—from `J` to `I` or from `K` to `I`, Git can find commit `I`.  Using the backwards arrow from `I` itself, Git can find `H`, and so on, all the way back to the very first commit, where the action stops.

All *unreachable* commits—those not found by starting at all of these starting (ending?) points and walking backwards—will be removed at some point, so they effectively don't exist.  For the purposes of most Git commands that walk through the graph, that's the case as well.  (There are some special purpose recovery tricks that let you get deleted commits back for 30 days, but filter-branch does not honor these.)

#### What all this means for filter-branch

The job of `git filter-branch` is to *copy commits*.  It walks through the graph, using the starting (ending?) points you give it to find all reachable commits.  It saves their hash IDs in a temporary file.  Then, going in the opposite direction—i.e., forwards in time instead of Git's usual backwards—it extracts each of these commits.  That is, it checks it out, so that all the files in that snapshot are available.  Then filter-branch applies the filter(s), and then *makes a new commit from the resulting files*.  So if your filter makes a simple change, the result is a *copy* of the original graph:

```
A--B--C------G--H   <-- master, origin/master
    \       /
     D--E--F
```

becomes:

```
A'-B'-C'-----G'-H'  <-- master, origin/master
    \       /
     D'-E'-F'
```

What happens to the original commits?  Well, they are still there: what filter-branch does with the names that found them is to *rename* them, using `refs/original/` in front of their internal full names:

```
A--B--C------G--H   <-- refs/original/refs/heads/master, refs/original/refs/remotes/origin/master
    \       /
     D--E--F
```

One reason filter-branch has so many filter options is that this process is dreadfully slow.  It takes a long time to extract every file into a temporary directory.  So some filters can work without extracting the files at all, which goes much (much!) faster.

Another reason is that sometimes we don't want to copy *every* commit, we only want to copy *some* commits that meet some criteria.  That's the case for the `--subdirectory-filter`: it only copies a commit if it changes files (with respect to its parent commit(s)) that involve the subdirectory in question.  So it can skip extracting a lot of commits, in some cases.  Of course, the subdirectory filter also renames the files along the way, as it extracts-and-recommits, to remove the subdirectory path.  The result is that a larger commit graph is copied to a newer, smaller one:

```
A--B--C------G--H   <-- master
    \       /
     D--E--F
```

might become:

```
B'--G'--H'   <-- master
 \ /
  E'
```

The retained `refs/original/refs/heads/master` will still point to commit `H`, while the rewritten `refs/heads/master` will point to copied commit `H'`.  Note that the first commit in the new graph is `B'`, not `A'`, since `A'` did not have the subdirectory in question.

There's also a very important side question here: *Which reference(s) does filter-branch update after it finishes all the commit-copying?*  The answer is in the documentation:

> The command will only rewrite the *positive* refs mentioned in the
>    command line (e.g. if you pass *a..b*, only *b* will be rewritten).

Since you are using `--all`, this will rewrite all the `origin/*` remote-tracking names.  (`--all` counts as a positive mention of every ref here.  There is some extra trickiness with tags: if you want to rewrite your tags, add `--tag-name-filter cat` as a filter.)

#### Summary

After your filter-branch operation, you have a series of `refs/original/*` names that point to the original (pre-filtering) commits, renamed from their original full names.  You have a series of new updated references, including all your branch names (`refs/heads/*`) and remote-tracking names (`refs/remotes/*`) pointing to the last of whichever commits got copied.

The new repository will be *bigger* than the original, because it *contains* the original, plus the copied commits.  See the **checklist for shrinking a repository** section of [the `git filter-branch` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html), near the end.  But note that if you use `git clone` to copy the filtered repository, that copies only your *branch* names, not your *remote-tracking* names, so at this point, if you did not already create a branch for each remote-tracking name, you should do that now.

Alternatively, you can just keep the copied repository in place after removing all the `refs/original/` namespace names.  You can then `git checkout develop` to create your own `refs/heads/develop` based on your (filtered) `refs/remotes/origin/develop`, and so on.  All you are doing is creating new names—the commits themselves are what Git really cares about, and they're referenced by the rewritten remote-tracking names—and then checking out that particular commit, so that it's in your index and work-tree.  (The `git branch -t` commands we showed at the beginning created the names without copying the commits to index-and-work-tree.)

Comment: This is fantastic, I truly appreciate your guidance and explanation! I fully understand what I need to do now.